# How can I edit the origins of my notifications?

Tags: javascript, python, notifications, electron

Well, I am searching for ways to send a notification to windows, I tried 2 different ways that worked, but not as I liked, the first was with python, I tried 3 different libraries:

> Pynotifier, Plyer and win10toast

Pynotifier code:

```
import pynotifier

pynotifier.Notification('PyNotifier', 'message', 5).send()
```

win10toast code:

```
import win10toast

toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast(
    'Toast',
    'Toast message',
)
```

plyer code:

```
import plyer.platforms.win.notification
from plyer import notification

notification.notify("Plyer", "message", "app name", app_icon=None, timeout=5)
```

I have 2 problems with it, first one: I want to create an executable with it, but the only library that works is "plyer", the other ones, returns this error when I execute the ".EXE" file:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 865, in run
  File "win10toast\__init__.py", line 93, in _show_toast
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1144, in resource_filename
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'win10toast' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I want to solve this, the second one is when I execute the code to send the notification, the title isn't the title, it comes "python", not the title I set, but the notification's origin, I can't send images for now, but imagine like that:

```
 _____________
|icon  PYTHON |
|_____________|
```

But I don't want this "python", I want the title I set, even when I do it with JavaScript with electron:

```
console.log(Notification.permission)

function showNotification(msg) {
    notification = new Notification(
        'NotifyMe',
        {
            body: msg,
            icon: "images/favicon.ico"
        }
    )
}

if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    showNotification("NEW NOTIFICATION")
} else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
        console.log(permission)
    })
}
```

it comes the same thing, but with "electron.app.Electron".